# Macbook pro 16 inch 2019 noisy display in chrome after waking up from sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, sleep-wake, google-chrome, vga

I have this issue sometimes when my mac is waking up from sleep. Some applications like Google Chrome
A part or whole of the application is turning into a noise picture and until I restart the system, it won't fix.

In this screenshot I have opened inspect view of google chrome. In some websites, one part or whole of the website also, is being displayed like this.

I've updated to the latest version of Mac (Catalina 10.15.7) and chrome (86.0.4240.183 (Official Build) (x86_64)). Also this issue is happening when I use the main display or external display too. No differences.

[image]

Comment: Boot into Safe Mode, does it still happen? Honestly that looks like (potentially) a hardware issue. Something in the video subsystem (video "card," cabling, etc) is failing. But it would be best to troubleshoot this issue as software first. Like Safe Mode, updating apps and/or the OS, possibly even wiping the drive and installing macOS from scratch.

Comment: Actually this happened only few times. and I don't know exactly what should happen to be occurred. But I know those times that it happened, was after waking up from sleep.

Comment: I've updated Google Chrome and my Mac OS, as I had pointed in my question. Is not possible for me to re install the OS again, for now. I'm not sure if Mac has any possibility  to reinstall graphic card drivers or not!
Note that this issue was started after I've upgraded to Catalina Mac OS

Answer (score 6):

This bug has [been reported](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1068170) to the Chromium team since 06/04/2020.

### Impacted Apps

This seems to affect all Chromium-based applications include Google Chrome, Brave, Electron, and probably others.

### Symptoms

In my case it happens sometimes after sleep.

### Cause

Chrome is saying its an Apple issue. Apple saying its an AMD issue.

> 29/01/2020: We're continuing to press this issue with Apple. They recently report that the bug has been reproduced and that AMD is investigating it.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1068170#c206

There also appears to be [some drama](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.forbes.com%2Fsites%2Fgordonkelly%2F2020%2F06%2F11%2Fapple-macos-macbook-pro-google-chrome-display-problem%2Famp%2F&oq=cache%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.forbes.com%2Fsites%2Fgordonkelly%2F2020%2F06%2F11%2Fapple-macos-macbook-pro-google-chrome-display-problem%2Famp%2F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.3107j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) between Apple and Google in terms of whose problem it is.

### Workarounds

#### Kill Chromium GPU Helper process (activity monitor)

This method is advantageous as it doesn't require restarting your browser and potentially losing your tabs.

- Open Activity Monitor
- Search for `(GPU)`

All Chromium-based apps including Electron apps will have one or more GPU helper processes. E.g. `Spotify Helper (GPU)`, `Code Helper (GPU)`, `Google Chrome Helper (GPU)`.

- Force Kill the GPU process of the offending app. **NOTE: You may have to do this multiple times.**
- You should see the page go white, and then the green bars should no longer be visible.

NOTE: This doesn't always work, see the Chromium bug thread below for more information.

Thanks to: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1068170#c188

**Alternative: Use Terminal.app**

An alternative to Activity Monitor is to use Terminal.app

```
killall "Google Chrome Helper (GPU)"
```

#### Disable Hardware Acceleration

- Visit `chrome://settings/system` in the browser
- Disable `Use hardware acceleration when available`.

#### Other alternatives

- Restart the app
- Restart your computer