# Very strange green artifacts in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, graphics

I have no idea what this is, restarting chrome and my machine doesn't fix it, it seems random and it affects things randomly, and goes away randomly.

Notice this issue comes up with I take the macOS screenshot too.  I think it must be a bug with Chrome, not sure if it's my laptop or macOS too?

Not sure how to google for this either, it's a big mystery, and makes a lot of pages unusable unless I’m fortunate enough for it to just go away

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem. But **not only with the Google Chrome** app, but everywhere. The screen had several, thoroughly horizontal bars. For me it was due to the *graphics card* that was defective. After replacing this, everything worked again. With you, it’s probably not because of the graphics card.

Comment: Whats the mac model, chrome version and macOS version? Does it **only** happen in Chrome?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

16" Macbook Pro?

It sounds similar to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/414669) (although most users report blue lines, not green).

Does it still happen if you turn off hardware acceleration in Chrome?

Comment: Turning off hardware acceleration fixed this

Comment: that's great, but how do you handle desktop apps that uses Chromium under the hood, i.e. Whatsapp Desktop, I've seen it happen to me

Answer (score 1):

According to the Google Chrome team, this is [a problem in macOS](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1068170#c249). According to [a more recent comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1068170#c257) on that same page, there might be a fix included in the upcoming macOS 11.4.

Answer (score 0):

**ISSUE:**
I have the dreaded Green Bar Noise in Chrome on MacBook Pro 16"
with the AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 8GB Video, running Big Sur 11.0.1

**SOLUTION:**
Go the Chrome Settings, ( 3 Dots on the Right hand side of the Address bar),
then Select SETTINGS, then ADVANCED, then SYSTEM then,
Turn off '**Use hardware acceleration when available**'

[image: Hardware Acceleration]

For me the problem is resovled.

Comment: This is rather temporary workaround that makes websites slow, especially those containing graphics/videos.